# Trigger click event on a div (maybe just relate to Google Keep)

Tags: javascript, events, google-keep

I'm trying to click a button on Google Keep via JavaScript, but the event doesn't seem to fire/caught. It works fine with real mouse, though...

I tried with its parents (and grandparents, too) but to no avail.

Here is what I am trying at the moment

```
[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[role=button]'), function (e) { return e.innerText == 'DONE' })[0].click();
```

http://imgur.com/cpQl63M

Comment: Don't post an image, post [mcve]

Comment: @yezzz, example added...